# Can't get element with Python Selenium find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I'm having trouble getting a specific element in the page I want to scrape. The content is wrapped in a weird  tag, and not sure if it's an iframe. I also tried with CSS_SELECTOR, but anything coming after the mentioned tag throws an error.

The page I want to scrape:
https://connect.echobotsales.de/#/company/YwOwE8kYmN

what I'm doing:

```
try:
    telephone_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//dynamicelements/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/a").text
    print(telephone_element)
except Exception as e:
    print("error", e)
```

The error I get:

```
error Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//dynamicelements/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/a"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=113.0.5672.63); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
```

Comment: the XPath is correct. Could it be that dynamicelements-element is causing the problem. It is not a html-element...?
What gives you this XPath: `//span[@ng-if='!company.phoneIsBlacklisted']/a` ?

Comment: Same error stacktrace. I think indeed the dynamiceleents-element is the problem. Any element before that tag is picked up fine.

Comment: What if you use a `css selecter`: span[ng-if='!company.phoneIsBlacklisted'] > a

Comment: I used:
company_phone = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[ng-if='!company.phoneIsBlacklisted'] > a")


error Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@ng-if='!company.phoneIsBlacklisted']/a"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://connect.echobotsales.de/#/company/YwOwE8kYmN")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//dynamicelements/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/a")))
print(element.text)
print(element.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

**Console output:**

```
+49 89996400
+49 89996400

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Another option:** Although the above used XPath expression is correct, you can try using the below XPath expression also to locate the desired element. Refer the below line of code:

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span//a[contains(@href,'tel')]")))
```

Answer (score 1):

While I have used Xpath you provided, it is showing me exact phone number. Means your xpath is valid one.
You can interact with that element with wait first. People use one wait only, but I uses 2 for safe side, use 2 waits to make sure that element is intractive.

so you can use following approach:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    telephone_xpath = "//dynamicelements/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/a"
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, telephone_xpath))
    wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, telephone_xpath))
    try:
        
        telephone_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, telephone_xpath).text
        print(telephone_element)
    except Exception as e:
        print("error", e)
```

Hope this will help you.
You may check it from screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Mmmm... still getting this error, which I believe happens when it can't find the element?
error Message: 
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55a6ff9e2133 <unknown>
#1 0x55a6ff716966 <unknown>
#2 0x55a6ff7530dc <unknown>
.....
#18 0x7f78ff4bf402 <unknown>

Comment: I ran the code, and it gives me telephone number from print statement.

Comment: Thanks, it worked in the end. Thanks for your time to explain!